# Pyomo constraint: use continuous variable as boolean?

Tags: optimization, constraints, pyomo

I am looking to use a continuous variable in a bool statement. For example, if m.N[t] is the continuous variable, I'd like to do the following:

@m.Constraint(m.t)
def success(m,t):
if m.N[t] == 0:
return m.d[t] = 0

I get the following errors:

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint success with
index 0: ValueError: Constraint 'success[0]': rule returned None.

```
Constraint rules must return either a valid expression, a 2- or 3-member
tuple, or one of Constraint.Skip, Constraint.Feasible, or
Constraint.Infeasible.  The most common cause of this error is forgetting
to include the "return" statement at the end of your rule.
```

ERROR: Constructing component 'success' from data=None failed: ValueError:
Constraint 'success[0]': rule returned None.

```
Constraint rules must return either a valid expression, a 2- or 3-member
tuple, or one of Constraint.Skip, Constraint.Feasible, or
Constraint.Infeasible.  The most common cause of this error is forgetting
to include the "return" statement at the end of your rule.
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. There is a way to simulate a binary variable by imposing the constraint

```
x*(1-x) = 0
```

but that is much worse than just using a binary variable.

To be complete: there is a GDP (Generalized Disjunctive Programming) extension.